# Updating functional component props doesn't change styling

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-functional-component

I have this function component for rendering a span as a bar. When I render the component, I pass the prop `scrolled` as `false`. Then, jQuery updates the attribute to `true` when I have scrolled 150 pixels. I know it's not good practice to use jQuery, and I am migrating from it. For now, I want to get this to work as I am still learning functional components.

```
export default function Button(props) {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState( props.scrolled );
  useEffect(() => {
    setScrolled(props.scrolled);
  }, [scrolled]);

  return (
    <HamburgerButton scrolled={scrolled}>
      <p>{scrolled}</p> 
      <span></span>
    </HamburgerButton>
  );
}
```

And this styled component definition:

```
const HamburgerButton = styled.div`
  ...
  span {
        background: ${props => props.scrolled === 'false' ? props.theme.white : props.theme.black};
  }
  ...
`;
```

When I scroll, I see the attribute `scrolled` has changed in the DOM from 'false' to 'true' but the spans stay white. Also, the paragraph tag with `{scrolled}` doesn't change from `false`.

Comment: You're doing a strict equality check with `===` but comparing a boolean to a string, so they won't ever be equal. Should just be `props.scrolled === false`

Comment: @Jayce444 implementing this change keeps the element white and doesn't change when the `scrolled` attribute changes. It appears that when jQuery changes the attribute, it converts the boolean to a string.

Comment: @Casey `!props.scrolled || props.scrolled === 'false' ? props.theme.white : props.theme.black`? Cover both scenarios

Comment: I tried `background: ${props => !props.scrolled || props.scrolled === false ? props.theme.white : props.theme.black};` but it still doesn't update the color when `scrolled="true"` is applied as an attribute to the component.

Comment: What is the purpose of the react hooks? Seems you can just pass `props.scrolled` directly to the `HamburgerButton`. All you did was save the initial `props.scrolled` value in state, updated it with the same value the first time the effect is called and nothing else ever changes the value of `scrolled` to trigger the effect again.

Comment: @DrewReese the purpose was to change the styling of the component when the page is scrolled - white nav, black button - black nav, white button. The issue ended up being the scrolled prop was never changing in the parent component. This question helped me learn how useEffect works and I leveraged that to change the state of the button when the page had been scrolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue**
Your code memoizes the `props.scrolled` value in the hooks.

```
export default function Button(props) {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState( props.scrolled ); // state initialized
  useEffect(() => { // hook called first render
    setScrolled(props.scrolled); // state updated with same value
  }, [scrolled]); // state value never changes during life of component so effect hook never recomputes

  return (
    <HamburgerButton scrolled={scrolled}>
      <p>{scrolled}</p> 
      <span></span>
    </HamburgerButton>
  );
}
```

**Solution**
You can directly pass prop to HamburgerButton

```
export default function Button(props) {
  return (
    <HamburgerButton scrolled={props.scrolled}>
      <p>{props.scrolled}</p> 
      <span></span>
    </HamburgerButton>
  );
}
```

Or use the hooks and use the correct dependency

```
export default function Button(props) {
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState( props.scrolled );
  useEffect(() => {
    setScrolled(props.scrolled); // update state
  }, [props.scrolled]); // with the value that changes here

  return (
    <HamburgerButton scrolled={scrolled}>
      <p>{scrolled}</p> 
      <span></span>
    </HamburgerButton>
  );
}
```

Use a positive comparison for the true branch of a ternary and leverage javascript's truthy/falsey values. If `scrolled` is `true`, or any other truthy value, render black, if fasley, (`false, 0, null, undefined`) render white.

```
const HamburgerButton = styled.div`
  ...
  span {
    background: ${props => props.scrolled ? props.theme.black : props.theme.white};
  }
  ...
`;
```

or

```
const HamburgerButton = styled.div`
  ...
  span {
    background: ${props => props.theme[props.scrolled ? 'black' : 'white']};
  }
  ...
`;
```